# Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I inquire how to send information from local storage to spring, there was no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827432/send-array-from-local-storage-to-spring, so i tried to do in that way and the new problems appeared
As of now JS it looks like :

```
function sendToJavaBuy() {
    cartWhisky = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
    var newArray = [];
    var i = 0;
    for(i in cartWhisky){
        newArray[i] = cartWhisky[i].name +"_"+ cartWhisky[i].quantity;
        i++;
        console.log("newArray[i]"+newArray);

    }
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            type: "POST",
            data :
                JSON.stringify(newArray),
            url: 'buySuccessfulWhisky',

            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.href = "buySuccessfulWhisky";
                //console.log(data)
            }
        });
 }
```

Java:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "buySuccessfulWhisky", method ={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView view(@RequestBody List<String> newArray) {
        System.out.println(newArray);
        System.out.println();
        for(String properties:newArray) {
            String[] split = properties.split("_");
            String name = split[0];
            Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
            System.out.println("name:= "+name);
            System.out.println("quantity:= "+quantity);

//        whiskyService.changeInfoInDB(name, quantity);
        }
        List<WhiskyDTO> whiskyDTOs =whiskyService.seeAllWhisky();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("viewAvailableWhisky", whiskyDTOs);
        modelAndView.setViewName("whisky");
        return modelAndView;
    }
   }
```

I see an exception on the UI:
I read forum, but can't understand what can I do with this mistake.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> - Tue Aug 09 12:11:39 EEST 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad    Request, status=400). Required request body is missing:
>     public    org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>     com.example.controller.buy.SuccessfulBuyWhiskey.view(java.util.List)

[image]

maybee I have problems, becouse of this:
I do table to HTML from JS

```
var cartArray = listCart();
var table ='';
displayShow();

function displayShow() {
    table = '';
    for(var r in cartArray){
        table +='<tr><td width="50"><img src="' + cartArray[r].photo + '" width=35 height=80></td>\
        <td width="100">'+cartArray[r].name+'</td>\
        <td width="150">'+cartArray[r].describe+'</td>\
        <td width="100">\
        <table width="80"><td align="right"><button class="minus" data-name="'+cartArray[r].name+'">-</button></td>\
        <td align="center"> '+cartArray[r].quantity +'</td>\
        <td align="left"><button class="plus" data-name="'+cartArray[r].name+'">+</button></td></tr></table>\
        </td>\
            +<td width="50" align="center">'+cartArray[r].price+'</td>\
            +<td width="80">' + cartArray[r].total + '</td>\
            +<td width="50"><button class="deleteItem" data-name="'+cartArray[r].name+'">X</button></td></tr>';
    }
    $('#trash').html(table);
    $("#totalCart").html(totalPriceInCart());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer, problem was in js, new code:

```
  cartWhisky = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
    var newArray = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (i in cartWhisky) {
        newArray[i] = cartWhisky[i].name + "_" + cartWhisky[i].quantity+"_"+cartWhisky[i].photo;
        i++;
    }
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: '/buySuccessfulWhisky',
        data:

        JSON.stringify(newArray),
        success: function (msg) {
            window.location.href = "warehouseWhisky";
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be missing a forward slash in your controller mapping

change `@RequestMapping(value = "buySuccessfulWhisky", method ={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})`

to `@RequestMapping(value = "/buySuccessfulWhisky", method= RequestMethod.POST)`

Hope that works

Comment: How does a missing slash explain the 400 status code?

Comment: if I do only RequestMethod.POST, I see new misstake:

There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Your ajax code `type: "POST"` says you are making a post request to your controller,  then how can you get error while using `RequestMethod.POST`.. however the error says it correctly that GET request is not supported.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've faced the missing slash problem at times when I missed it. The request URL becomes invalid or say, incorrect if I miss the forward slash. Even on my current running project I tried to remove slash and it gave me 400 Bad request. Also, the 400- Bad request error means any required parameter by the controller might be missing.

Answer (score -1):

In your case why don't you send the whole `cartWhisky`  object in the ajax. In java create a class which have fields : `name` and `quantity`. Create getters and setters and a daffault constructor for the class and you do not have to do `JSON.stringify(cartWhisky)` .

You can directly : `data : cartWhisky`.

In your controller you can :

```
public ModelAndView view(@RequestBody List<CartWhisky> newArray) { ..
```

Now the class should look like this:

```
public class CartWhisky { 
   private String name;
   private String quantity;

   public CartWhisky(){
   }

   public setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   public getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
   public setQuantity(String quantity){
      this.quantity = quantity;
   }
   public getQuantity(){
      return this.quantity;
   }
 ...
}
```

This constructor is created by default if you do not specify any other constructors but if you do, you have to create a default one (that looks like the one in the example).

You can also have other fields, methods and constructors but thouse are required.

Comment: Why would the fact that List is an interface make any difference?

Comment: Yes @MarkChorley you have a point of course when we are talking about @RequestBody does not metter if is an `interface` or not! Thanks

Comment: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.example.controller.buy.SuccessfulBuyWhiskey$cartWhisky]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ae6334f; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]